# PHPMailer Change the senders name

Tags: php, phpmailer

I'm having trouble setting the name that's sent with mailings sent using the PHPMailer class.

I've written the following function so that it can be used in a similar way the php's bulit in `mail()` function.

```
function pmail($to, $subject, $message, $headers = "", $attachments = "")
{
    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/inc/class.phpmailer.php");
    //include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/inc/class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded

    $defaultEmail = "reply@example.com";
    $defaultEmailName = "Web Mailer";

    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    $mail->IsSMTP();                                // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "mail.example.com";         // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = false;                      // enables SMTP debug information (for testing, 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only, false = off)
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                       // enable SMTP authentication
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                    // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Host       = "mail.example.com";         // sets the SMTP server
    $mail->Port       = 25;                         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
    $mail->Username   = "###";                      // SMTP account username
    $mail->Password   = "###";                      // SMTP account password
    $mail->SetFrom( ($headers['fromEmail'] != "" ? $headers['fromEmail'] : $defaultEmail), ($headers['fromName'] != "" ? $headers['fromName'] : $defaultEmailName) );
    $mail->AddReplyTo( ($headers['replyToEmail'] != "" ? $headers['replyToEmail'] : $defaultEmail), ($headers['replyToName'] != "" ? $headers['replyToName'] : $defaultEmailName) );
    $mail->AddAddress($to);
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    $mail->AltBody = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);

    foreach($attachments as $attachment) {
        //$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment example
        $mail->AddAttachment($attachment);
    }

    if(!$mail->Send()) {
        //echo "Mailer Error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        //echo "Message sent!";
        return true;
    }
}
```

When testing with something like so;

`pmail("test@test.com", "test email", "test message here");`

Everything works fine, the from address shows up as `reply@example.com` in the headers as expected, however the name that I see in the inbox of the recipient is not `Web Mailer` its the default account associated with the user whos credentials are used to send the email.
In the headers the from name does show up as Web Mailer, but its the inbox where I want to see it

We are unable to set up more user accounts on our system to allow us to just make a new one with the desired name and email, therefore we have to send it via an existing user account. 
In this case mine, and emails get sent with my name attached, but we want the name to show up as Web Mailer.

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out my function does work as intended.
Because I was receiving emails from this system to internal addresses, they all automatically had me in their address book, therefore as the address used to send out the emails was associated with my personal address, they saw my name instead of "Web Mailer".

When testing with an external email account the senders name is listed correctly.

Comment: lol I didn't this, same happened to me. when used external email address, It was coming correctly.

Comment: @MaulikVora annoying eh? I wasted so much time on this.

Comment: yeah @Novocaine but you saved me my time here. ;-)

Answer (score 12):

If you use PHP Mailer API of GitHub, you can use this to set the Sender Name:

```
$mail->SetFrom("$youremail ", "Your Name");
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is what the OP was looking for, but it was what _I_ was looking for, so thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

I once used this php code and it worked well: (it displayed what's below, not my gmail credentials)

```
$headers = "From: Cartrader UK <noreply@cartrader.co.uk";
```

.
.
.

```
if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers)) {
echo "Mail sent successfully";
} else {
echo "There was some problem sending the E-Mail";
}
```

Maybe it helps you.

EDIT:
I would try change your line with SetFrom to:

```
$mail->SetFrom($defaultEmail,$defaultEmailName);
```

Comment: This would work with the php built in mail() function, however im using the phpmailer class to send the emails and unfortunately this does not work quite the same.

Comment: OK, I understand. One more thing though, do you really need that ternary operator there? If you want name displayed to be "Web Mailer" can you just assign it directly?

Comment: No I don't need the ternary operator right now, however there might be some use for it in future development (multiple different domain websites requiring different email addresses) which is why I've implemented it like that.

Comment: OK, but I would recommend you to change it just to check whether it is not that line causing the issue. Unless you are 100% sure it isn't..

Comment: I was pretty sure it wasn't an issue, but I did try it anyway. Unfortunately no change.

Comment: OK, than last thing I can think of is version of phpmailer you use is older than 5.0. Is that a case? If not a dont know where the problem might be..

Comment: I'm using v5.2.2 of phpmailer so I guess no problem there.

Answer (score -1):

You can set in your mail.php

```
$headers = "From: Your Name <yourname@example.com>";
```

Comment: This does not relate to the PHPMailer class. What you've provided is for a standard php email which this question is not about.